# Why won’t the JVM terminate when I close all the application windows?

Tags: java, swing

The answer for this that I've seen in many forums is that - The AWT event dispatcher thread is not a daemon thread. You must explicitly call System.exit to terminate the JVM.

How not being a daemon thread can cause JVM to close that application. As, it says that only after all non-daemon thread die, program exits.

When we create a simple `JFrame` and do not issue `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`, and when we run the program and when JVM exits, the program is still running

Comment: If you have a frame, try `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, I do know that. I was asking the reason that why does it not close and we need to explicitly close it?

Comment: There are applications that might just need to hide (closing the window might just set the jframe to visible false). This corresponds to different behaviors for different necessities, that's all.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html#windowevents

Comment: I think your confusing your application closing and the JVM terminating. Your application runs within the JVM, therefore, if the JVM terminates, so does your application, but not the other way round

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think, Mercenary is confusing closing the window with closing the program. This is a big difference.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Hmm I think you are right :-) Actually, this was one of the question asked in an interview. I misunderstood it. However, my actual question still stands. I wanted to know about why doesn't the program exit once you run it (without giving `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`)

Comment: @Mercenary In fact, it's simple (as always): When starting a Swing application, the Swing framework also starts a background thread for handling GUI issues. This is the famous _event dispatcher thread_ (aka EDT). If you simply close the window, it usually is only hidden, and the EDT still exists. So the JVM cannot terminate because - simple as that - a thread still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [Thread JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) state...

> All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning
>   from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that
>   propagates beyond the run method.

You can force the JVM to terminate by calling `System.exit`

I think your confusing your application closing and the termination of the JVM. Your application runs within the JVM, so it's impossible for the JVM to terminate and leave your application running

Comment: Thanks! And I think you are right :-) Posted it above - but anywas posting it again here : Actually, this was one of the question asked in an interview. I misunderstood it. However, my actual question still stands. I wanted to know about why doesn't the program exit once you run it (without giving `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`)

Comment: Once started, the event dispatching thread is started, this is a non-daemon thread, thus allows the main thread (that called main) to exit, without causing the JVM to terminate

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it! And just one more thing, as per the Thread doc : "All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method". When does 'or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method' occur?

Comment: Pretty much any uncaught exception will do this, along with all Errors

Answer (score 0):

The default for JFrame is (the equivalent to) HIDE_ON_CLOSE, so it simply hides the frame (you can still bring it back) hence the application is still running, so the JVM won't exit.

(however WHY it is the default, I do not have an answer to.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should refer the API specification first. This is how its designed.
It clearly says:

> Unlike a Frame, a JFrame has some notion of how to respond when the user attempts to close the window. The default behavior is to  simply hidethe JFrame when the user closes the window. To change the default behavior, you invoke the method setDefaultCloseOperation(int). To make the JFrame behave the same as a Frame instance, use setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE).
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

So it simply calls setVisible(false); for default close operation

you can check source for  protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) in JFrame class.

```
/**
 * Processes window events occurring on this component.
 * Hides the window or disposes of it, as specified by the setting
 * of the <code>defaultCloseOperation</code> property.
 *
 * @param  e  the window event
 * @see    #setDefaultCloseOperation
 * @see    java.awt.Window#processWindowEvent
 */
protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e) {
    super.processWindowEvent(e);

    if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
        switch(defaultCloseOperation) {
          case HIDE_ON_CLOSE:
             setVisible(false);
             break;
          case DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE:
             dispose();
             break;
          case DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE:
             default:
             break;
          case EXIT_ON_CLOSE:
              // This needs to match the checkExit call in
              // setDefaultCloseOperation
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, MadProgrammer's comment makes sense here.